# Creating a 2D array in F# from a sequence of arrays with similar dimension

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a sequence of int arrays, all of the same dimension;

I wish to create a 2D array in which each line n of the 2D array is the nth term in the sequence.

for example, if my sequence is

```
{[|1 ; 2; 3|] , [|4 ; 5; 6|] , [|7 ; 8; 9|]}
```

the function should return a 2D array

```
[|[|1;2;3;],[|4 ; 5; 6|],[|7 ; 8; 9|]|]
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly changing your sequence shows the easiest way (which will work with any combination of inner sequences / arrrays / lists

```
let t =array2D [[|1 ; 2; 3|] ; [|4 ; 5; 6|] ; [|7 ; 8; 9|]];;
```

Comment: This works for short sequences and array lengths, but how could I produce a function such that I can do it for longer sequences and arrays? what if my sequence has 1000 elements, all of which are 50 element arrays?

Comment: Well you just do `array2D somevar`